# Error when updating from select on same table EVEN when using primary key in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

That is my query:

```
UPDATE status as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT status.id, status.deployment_id FROM status
) as t2
SET t1.task_id=t2.deployment_id
WHERE t1.id=t2.id;
```

And that is the response:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table **without a WHERE that uses a KEY column** To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.
```

But I actually USE primary keys in my query, why I still get such result?

ps
I use MySQL.

### UPDATE

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2265f

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the issue is the subquery, which is not needed.  You could write this as:

```
UPDATE status as t1 JOIN
       status t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id
    SET t1.task_id = t2.deployment_id;
```

Of course, if `id` is a primary key, then it is unique and never `NULL`, so it is much simpler to write:

```
UPDATE status s
    SET s.task_id = s.deployment_id;
```